# Laurent Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Wikipedia says: "The Laurent polynomial ring $R[X, X^{−1}]$ is isomorphic to $R[\mathbb{Z}]$. More generally, the Laurent polynomial ring in n variables, $R[X_{1}, X_{1}^{−1},...,X_{n}, X_{n}^{−1}]$, is isomorphic to $R[\mathbb{Z}^n]$".

How can I show the case in n variables? I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595044/laurent-polynomials-ring) for the case in 1 variable, and I am not convinced since they do not offer a rigurous proof and they quote a theorem without a proof.
Maybe we can use somehow the fact that [they are the localization of $R[X_{1},...,X_{n}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631025/viewing-laurent-polynomials-as-a-localization-of-rx).

Comment: $(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ corresponds to the monomial $X_1^{a_1}\cdots X_n^{a_n}$.

Comment: But yes, you can also think of this ring as a localization, but not of $R[X^n]$ but of $R[X_1,\dots, X_n]$, where the multiplicative set is the set of all non-constant monomials. Or as a quotient in which you add $Y_1,\dots, Y_n$ such that $Y_iX_i=1$.

Comment: @Javi I meant that but I wrote something different thanks for the correction!

Comment: Btw, I have edited the comment, I wrote "all polynomials with no constant term",which is not even multiplicative because it does not contain $1$. The smalles multiplicative set containing all the variables is made of the non-constant monomials and $1$. This is analogous to the 1-variable case, where the multiplicative set consist of the powers of the variable.

Comment: @Javi the problem is I would like to extend the group homomorphism you suggest to a ring isomorphism and I am not sure how and why can I do that rigorously.

Comment: It is literally a linear extension. If you define a group homomorphism $f:G\to A$ where  $A$ is an $R$-algebra, then you just need to define $F:R[G]\to A$ by $$F(r_1 g_1+\cdots +r_n g_n)=r_1f(g_1)+\cdots + r_n f(g_n).$$

Comment: In this case $g_i$ is an element of $G=\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most intuitive way to see the bijection is noting that each group element $(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ corresponds to the monomial $X_1^{a_1}\cdots X_n^{a_n}$. This correspondence between elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and monomials is clearly bijective (note that $(0,\dots, 0)\mapsto 1$).

Now, for a ring $R$ and group $G$, the elements of the [group ring](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Passman.pdf) $R[G]$ are (finite) $R$-linear combinations of elements of $G$. Addition and multiplication are defined in the obvious way and you can check that on the link.

Therefore, if we have a group homomorphism $f:G\to A^\times$, where $A$ is an $R$-algebra and $A^\times$ its group of units, there is a unique way to extend it to an $R$-algebra homomorphism $F:R[G]\to A$, given by linear extension, e.g.

$$F(r_1 g_1+\cdots +r_n g_n)=r_1f(g_1)+\cdots + r_n f(g_n).$$

where $g_i\in G$ and $r_i\in R$. We must also define $F(1)=1$. This property is called [the universal property of group rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Universal_Property).

With this definition you can check that $F(xy)=F(x)F(y)$ for all $x,y\in R[G]$ using that $f$ is a group homomorphism. To see that this is indeed unique, notice that if $H:R[G]\to A$ is another $R$-algebra homomorphism such that $H(g)=f(g)$ for all $g\in G$, then it is the case that $H=F$ (recall that an [$R$-algebra homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_homomorphism) must be $R$-linear and ring homomorphism).

In our case we have $G=\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $A$ is the Laurent polynomials. In this case, we take $f:\mathbb{Z}^n\to A^\times$ to be the correspondence stablished at the beginning. Clearly, all the monomials are invertible, so this map is well defined and it is easy to check that it is a group homomorphism since the variables commute with each other, so we have a ring homomorphism $F:R[\mathbb{Z}^n]\to A$.

Now we have to check that it is bijective. This is not difficult because we now that a Laurent polynomial is a linear combination of the form

$$\sum_{(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n} r_{a_1,\dots, a_n} X_1^{a_1}\cdots X_n^{a_n},$$

which clearly is the image under $F$ of the element

$$\sum_{(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n} r_{a_1,\dots, a_n}(a_1,\dots, a_n) $$
of $R[\mathbb{Z}^n]$.